# Calling tasks recursively on a tree structure

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, celery

I apologise if this is simply as a result of my mis-understanding. I have been searching around and reading through the docs and have been unable to come up with a solution that works for me.

I have a tree structure where each node can have any number of children. For every node, a new celery task will be instantiated to create it, which will then look over all the children and instantiate new tasks to create those. The reason for doing it this way is to take better advantage of the multi-threaded nature of celery. A single task that recursively creates the entire tree only ever seems to take advantage of a single thread.

Whilst I have been able to set my code up in a manner which does this, the issue I have is that I have some dependencies in the originating task which cannot be executed until the entire structure has completed being created. The code looks something like:

```
@app.task
def initial_task(tree_data):
    jobs = []
    for node in tree_data:
        jobs.append(recursive_task.s(node))
    job = group(jobs)
    result = job.apply_async()

    # Block execution until group is finished
    while not result.ready():
        time.sleep(0.5)

    ... do dependent stuff ...

@app.task
def recursive_task(node, parent=None):
    # Create node object
    node_obj = Node(node.name, parent=parent)

    jobs = []
    for child in node.children:
        jobs.append(recursive_task.s(child, node_obj))
    job = group(jobs)
    result = job.apply_async()

    return node_obj
```

The problem I have is that the sub-tasks of all the children do not block the completion of the first group of tasks and I don't know how to force that to be the case. Any help in this matter would be very much appreciated.

Because I need the ID of the node_obj when creating children, I can't simply recurse the tree and chain the tasks.

**Update:**
I have changed the code a little to try and cause a change to the outcome. The following code causes all child (including grandchild, great-grandchild etc) to be a direct child of the top-level node:

```
@app.task
def initial_task(tree_data):
    def _recursive_link_task(task_set, children):
        for child in children:
            task_set.link(create_node.s(child))

            if child.children:
                _recursive_link_task(task_set, child.children)


    for node in tree_data:
        s = create_node.s(None, node)
        if node.children:
            _recursive_link_task(s, node.children)
        s.apply_async()

@app.task
def create_node(parent, node):
    node_obj = Node(node.name, parent=parent)
    return (node_obj,)
```

I had expected that I might have a little more fortune with the above snippet of code - but as it's just the initial node object which is passed to all subsequent tasks, I am still no further in my attempts to get this tree structure generated.

Answer (score 2):

Use [chords](http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chords) to execute a task that is dependent upon the results of a bunch of tasks.

as i could not understand exactly how you needed the recursive tasks to be called, i implemented a [reference](https://gist.github.com/sreedom/f1be0c6d54137196487b) example of merge-sort.

**note** that this will not work on celery 3.2.0+ as calling `get` inside a task will result in Exception.

```
from celery import Celery, chord
app = Celery('tasks', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://')
app.conf.CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp'


def mergesort(list_obj):
    '''normal mergesort
    '''
    if len(list_obj) <= 1:
        return list_obj
    middle = len(list_obj) / 2
    left, right = list_obj[:middle], list_obj[middle:]
    return list(merge(list(mergesort(left)), list(mergesort(right))))

def merge(left, right):
    '''normal merge
    '''
    while 1:
        if left == []:
            for j in right:
                yield j
            break
        elif right == []:
            for j in left:
                yield j
            break
        elif left[0] < right[0]:
            yield left.pop(0)
        else:
            yield right.pop(0)

def merge2(left_r, right_r):
    '''celery merge
    '''
    left =left_r.get()
    right = right_r.get()
    while 1:
        if left == []:
            for j in right:
                yield j
            break
        elif right == []:
            for j in left:
                yield j
            break
        elif left[0] < right[0]:
            yield left.pop(0)
        else:
            yield right.pop(0)
@app.task
def merge_c(in_list):
    '''celery merge
    '''
    #unpack
    print '*'*21 + str( in_list)
    left, right = in_list
    return list(merge2(left, right))

@app.task
def same_object(l_obj):
    '''helper function to convert list to `result`
    '''
    return l_obj

@app.task
def mergesort_c(list_obj):
    '''celery mergesort
    '''
    if len(list_obj) <= 1:
        # make sure that you return a `result` object for merge
        return same_object.delay(list_obj)
    middle = len(list_obj) / 2
    left, right = list_obj[:middle], list_obj[middle:]
    # finish mergesort (left) and mergesort(right) and merge them
    res = chord([mergesort_c.s(left), mergesort_c.s(right)])(merge_c.s())
    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = [2,1, 3]
    #normal mergesort
    print mergesort(l) #[1, 2, 3, 3, 5]
    # with celery
    res = mergesort_c(l)
    print res.get()
```

Comment: Thanks for this. If I get the chance, I will see if I can apply it to work with the code I was writing. I had tried chaining tasks - perhaps a chord will provide better results.

Comment: good luck. meanwhile i will work on an answer that will not be deprecated with the new celery :)